# How do you insert msi into custom Windows install?

Tags: windows

How do you insert `msi` installers into a custom made (nLite) Windows XP install?

Comment: Should have been migrated to ServerFault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the image, files places in [image root]\$OEM$\$1 will be copied to the root of C drive during installation. You can then use nLite's runonce facility to execute whatever you want from that folder on first login (you can have nLite login once on first boot as administrator to kick off the runonce, then use `shutdown` to automatically reboot when finished). Use the switches found in the article moshen linked to to execute MSIs silently.

Comment: The $1 in %OEM%\$1 means the name of the file or that it also copies subdirectories?

Comment: The '$1' is just a the literal folder name. All files placed inside that folder will be copied to %homedrive% after install.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about nlite, but you may find some information [here](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/view/web/42/SESSID=c8fbeab2f8f1ba0344e6f763db78a818/).